# Error: error while writing the java class file

Tags: java, cmd, compiler-errors, javac

[check this image for a screenshot of my cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqg3K.png) I am trying to compile my java code and getting this error in command prompt and I know I am missing something very fundamental.
Thanks,

I have added entire code here,
My command line screenshot is also added.
i was able to compile the code earlier and now it just suddenly stops to work.

```
C:\Users\Jaysurya\Desktop\cnlab\crc>javac crc.java
 crc.java:2: error: error while writing crc: 
 C:\Users\Jaysurya\Desktop\cnlab\crc\crc.class
 class crc
 ^
 1 error
 C:\Users\Jaysurya\Desktop\cnlab\crc

>
```

My java file is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class crc
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int m,n,tbits,i;//m=size of data,,,,n=size of generator,,,,tbits= total size of data after the zeros have been appended.
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of data");
        m=sc.nextInt();
        int msg[] = new int[m];
        System.out.println("Enter the binary values");
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            msg[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the size of generator");
        n=sc.nextInt();
        int gen[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter the binary values");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            gen[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("The data bits are");
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(msg[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The generator bits are");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(gen[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();

        tbits=m+n-1;
        int apmsg[]=new int[tbits]; //append zeros
        int rem[]=new int[tbits];   //findind remainder
        int tcode[]=new int[tbits]; //received data
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            apmsg[i]=msg[i];    //appended msg
        }
        System.out.println("The data after appending zeros");
        for(i=0;i<apmsg.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(apmsg[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(i=0;i<apmsg.length;i++)
        {
            rem[i]=apmsg[i];    //copy to remainder
        }
        rem = calCRC(apmsg,gen,rem);    //calculate the crc and store in remaider

        for(i=0;i<rem.length;i++)
        {
            rem[i]=(apmsg[i]^rem[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("The crc code");
        for(i=0;i<rem.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(rem[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();

        //error detection

        System.out.println("Enter the recived crc code");
        for(i=0;i<tbits;i++)
        {
            tcode[i]=sc.nextInt();      //received data after transmitting
        }
        System.out.println("The recieved data is:");
        for(i=0;i<tbits;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(tcode[i]);     //received data after transmitting
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(i=0;i<tbits;i++)
        {
            rem[i]=tcode[i];    //copy to remainder
        }
        rem=calCRC(tcode,gen,rem);  //calculate crc
        for(i=0;i<rem.length;i++)
        {
            if(rem[i]!=0)       //if remainder is not zero error
            {
            System.out.println("Error");
            break;
            }
            if(i==rem.length-1)
            {
            System.out.println("Correct data");
            }
        }
    }

    static int[] calCRC(int apmsg[],int gen[],int rem[])
    {
        int i, c=0;
        while(true)
        {
            for(i=0;i<gen.length;i++)
            {
            rem[c+i]=(rem[c+i]^gen[i]);
            }
            while(rem[c]==0 && (c!=rem.length-1))
            {
            c++;
            }
            if((rem.length-c)<gen.length)
            break;
        }
        return(rem);
    }
}
```

Comment: the error still persists.

Comment: Please show your updated code, and please update the error message as it appears to be missing text

Comment: Can you please post the full error message or if that is all you are getting, try compiling with the -verbose option.  If that gives you no other details, then could you please create a [mcve]. As your question stands now, the error is unclear and you have not posted a compilable program that we could test out to try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: added entire code

Comment: Are you potentially executing the java class in another console? It seems like a permissions issue. First check if a crc.class file already exists in that folder and see if you can delete it from the File Explorer.  If you get a permission issue or file in use issue, then you know what is causing the trouble.

Comment: thanks, i have tried it already, but the error still seems to exist.and its the same error again.
Oh, it seems to happen for all my java files in the **cnlab **folder

Comment: Well, I am not sure what to tell you as this code compiles fine for me - see [here](https://ideone.com/Uu9mHx). Note, I was mistaken about telling you to make the class public. I had forgotten some of my java.  I suggest copying the code to a different a folder and try again. This has to be a permissions issue.

Comment: It can't find crc.java. It says so on the screen. Type `net helpmsg 2` and it returns `The system cannot find the file specified.` The name of what it can't find is in the error message.

Comment: I think @CatCat nailed it. Are your source files in that same folder `C:\Users\Jaysurya\Desktop\cnlab\crc` or do you have a subdirectory called `src` or something like that?

Comment: my source file is  `C:\Users\Jaysurya\Desktop\cnlab\crc\crc.java` and the picture says error while writing to `C:\Users\Jaysurya\Desktop\cnlab\crc\crc.class`

Comment: Do a dir of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your command line javac in Administrator mode

Comment: can you create an empty file in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem is You need to download again latest version of JDK from here [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-windows)

and after download go to the folder where you have download this and then right click and **Run as Administrator** , After successfully installation restart your system and open CMD and check java --version and javac --version ... if they give proper latest version means you have installed latest version and your problem will be solved...

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't from java JDK, searh for your notifications panel or in the Windows Security application and search for something like this:

[image: Protected folder access blocked || javac.exe]

If found just click on actions and then allow on device.
This problem is due to MS Defender Protected folders such as documents, desktop, etc.